# Firebase messaging keys differences

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm with a worry about the key of `firebase messaging` service, right now I got an error `HTTP 401`, and my surprise when I check the key, it is different than the key that I got at "Cloud Messaging" tab in google firebase console, however if I download the `json` file that I should put inside my app, the tag `current_key` doesn't match the key at "Cloud Messaging" tab, but matches with my key.

So I should ignore the json file downloaded from console and replace the `current_key` tag in my configuration file with the key that I can find at "Cloud Messaging" tab?

Answer (score 1):

They `current_key` value in google-services.json is not used by the firebase-messaging library but by other firebase libraries.

To send messages your **server** should use the API-KEY present in *settings > "Cloud Messaging"*